# Java program terminate with java result: 137

Tags: java, netbeans, cassandra, kill-process

I have a program written in  netbeans. The program read about 1,000,000 data from cassandra, process them and again write the result in cassandra. my program was running bout 9 hours but suddenly it was terminate with this bellow error:

```
java result: 137
```

I was read that these error means (128 + signalnember). in my case signalnember = 9 that is KILLSIGNAL. does any body know how can I remove this error?
please help me....

Comment: no.. not someone.. I don't know what is this error.. after about 9 hours my program terminate and the above error showed to me... what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's unlikely that the kill signal came from the program itself. What environment were you running it in?

Comment: Maybe your process getting killed by other administrative program/individual because it may be going beyond its assigned limits of memroy/cpu usage

Comment: I am running my program in netbeans on ubuntu 12.04..

Comment: you mean, may be the error is about memory limitation?

Comment: Can I trap the signal number 9?

Answer (score 7):

If there is a cgroup configuration limiting resources it might kill the process if if exceeds the limits (like consumed memory).
Check if the cgconfig service running. On RHEL:

```
service cgconfig status
```

You can also check for Java crash log files hs_err_.log for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Exit-code above 128 means that the process died because of a received
signal (exitCode = 128 + signalNumber).
==> In your case it was signal 9 (= SIGKILL

Comment: I know... so what should I do? if I re-run my program, is it possible that error represent again? how can I remove the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since its an outofmemory issue I would just split the operation into pieces if possible. I had to do it today actually where I was processing about 15,000,000 million records today. I just broke it up into chunks of 250,000 looped it and cleared my arrays.